# How do I stop Excel from converting value 0503E000 to 5.03E+02 automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, xls

Excel converting value 0503E000 to 5.03E+02 in any cell automatically in CSV
I tried to convert it to text number and general but after i save it and reopen it again
it goes back to 5.03E+02

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: just resize the column width and it should be displayed normally

Comment: Have you tried formatting the cell as text *before* entering the text?

Comment: tried resizing and formatting as text already no go ....

Comment: If you need to use the value as a hex number (i.e. you can't have it as a text string), you can nest `DEC2HEX` and `HEX2DEC` strings for the original number (e.g. `=DEC2HEX(HEX2DEC("0503E000"))` for your example). It may not help if you need to manipulate the csv file without it containing formulae, but it's another option besides formatting as text.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the key issue here is that you are using a CSV, which does not have the cell type embedded in it. Excel automatically tries to interpret the cell as having a scientific number which is why you are seeing *5.03E+02* instead of *0503E000*.

Try creating an Excel workbook and formatting all of the cells as text, and then pasting in the data. I tried it in Excel 2013 and it worked.

Comment: Yeah it works in Workbook, But unfortunately we have to use CSV for this purpose.....pity

Comment: So don't use Excel to view the contents, or run a macro on the cell, to convert it back or use slightly different syntax if you used 0x before the value I don't belive it would convert

Comment: I think we may have to lay this off ... because if we open it in another editor like notepad or notepad ++ it has the correct value....so I think cell has the correct value just displaying it wierdly in scientific notation....

Answer (score 37):

*If you can convert or control the CSV format*, you can force a column to parse as text in Excel by wrapping it in double quotes and prepending an equals sign.

Excel will carelessly discard precision in this format:

```
Value,0503E000,1234123412341234
```

Or even this format:

```
Value,"0503E000","1234123412341234"
```

Converting it to:

```
Value  |  5.03E+02  |  1234123412341230
```

*However*, adding the equals sign forces Excel to begrudgingly preserve your data:

```
Value,="0503E000",="1234123412341234"
```

…which opens as:

```
Value  |  0503E000  |  1234123412341234
```

Comment: Great solution when pasting from SQL

Comment: Also great solution when import data via "Get external data" in "Data" menu of Excel.

Comment: Great solution. The only (small) drawback is that you'll end up with formulaes instead of values. So just copy everything and then **paste values**, which will lead to a somewhat smaller Excel file.

Comment: Only if the file is in read only mode, if user edit the file and save. He will again loose the actual value

Comment: This answer might work, but thinking about this, I think its ideocracy: you have to format your CSVs in a way especially for Excel, having to adapt all other applications that need to use the CSV. Furthermore, when you export xlsx to csv, you have to manually edit the csv and change all of this in order to import it again...

Comment: @JHBonarius Yeah, Excel's default behavior is pretty frustrating, especially for a program that's primarily intended to work with numbers. It seems trouble enough to disqualify Excel from working with CSV files when I have the choice. My guess is that it's some backward compatibility thing from a time when higher precision was prohibitively expensive, and Office just can't break away from it.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of **Open**ing" the CSV file in Excel, select to **Import** the file (in Excel 2007-2010 you would navigate to the Data Ribbon / Get External Data / From Text).  Not sure about 2013 but there should be something similar.  When you do that, the Text Import wizard will open and afford you the opportunity to format the column containing that Value as Text, before Excel (not so helpfully) changes it to a numeric value.

Comment: This. I almost never open CSV files directly.

Comment: @pepoluan I don't understand what you have written.

Comment: Which part exactly you don't understand?

Comment: @pepoluan. The relevance of what you wrote to my answer.

Comment: I wrote "This", which meant I agree/support your answer. Then I wrote "I never open CSV files directly", referring to your explanation on using 'Import' instead of 'Open'.

Comment: @pepoluan  Thanks.  Had I understood `this`, the rest would have been clear. Guess I'm getting old :-(

Comment: I was hopeful that using "this" as a complete sentence would have died a quick death, but 4 years later, it's as strong as ever.

Comment: Unfortunately, when Excel **import**s CSV files, it does not handle multiline strings (even when perfectly quoted) as it does when **open**ing CSV files.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov I believe you are correct writing about the older `Legacy Wizard`. However, `Get & Transform` (aka `Power Query`) available since Excel 2010, handles that situation.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, it looks like *Power Query* is a downloadable add-on rather than built-in Excel 2010 functionality. (FWIW)

Comment: @AntonSamsonov That is correct for 2010. It came from Microsoft. Built-in in later versions of Excel. They may or may not still support that add-in. If they do not, and you still are running 2010, you could use the `OPEN` method if that works for you. Other problems with the `OPEN` method include automatic date translation which will be a problem if the file date format does not match your computer; automatic translation of fractions to dates; automatic translation of strings that look like numbers to numbers, etc. You could write a VBA routine that handles this if it is a problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

Start the cell with an apostrophe to force text interpretation:

```
'0502E000
```

Basically, this tells Excel not to parse the field as a number. Because there is an 'E' in the field, it looks like a number to Excel.
The apostrophe won't actually be entered into the cell:

```
[a1] '0502E000
[b1] =hex2dec(a1)
```

Cell 'b1' will display 84074496.

Comment: This works when entering directly in Excel, but not with CSV file.

Comment: When opening a csv file, the apostrophe will actually be entered into the cell

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the file (data fetched from DB table) through DATA option in MS excel then simply while loading just select “Do not detect data types” under “Data Type Detection” then load , this will keep the as it as format of data and loads excel, no need for any column conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Paste the data into a google spreadsheet.
Select the column ==> Format ==> Number => Custom format => type the number of digits to which you want format to happen (ex: 10 digits = 0000000000)

Comment: I would like to suggest better [Edit] you post,, since need to add some examples!!

Answer (score 0):

Found the Best Solution to this Problem! Here is how -

Use the Feature - **Get Data from Text/CSV**

*(can be found under Data Tab> Get Data> From File> From Text/CSV)*

Get Data from Text:
[image: Get Data from Text]

Then import the CSV from which you want to load data.
[image: Loading CSV]

In the pop-up, turn off Auto Data Type Detection.
[image: Turn off Auto Data Type Detection]

And the finally click load
[image: Load Button]

Voila! Your Data is imported to the sheet, without rounding off the numbers!
Successfully Imported Long Number Data without Rounding:
[image: Successfully Imported Long Number Data without Rounding]

If you get a different pop-up menu (old looking)
Steps will be slightly different, and you will need to manually click on column and set data type from **General to Text** to achieve similar result!

Comment: Thanks to Markus Meyer for turning my SS Links to Embedded Images! ( apparently to embed image one needs at least 10 reputation, while I had none LoL )

Answer (score -1):

With the default cell formatting, numbers with a zero in front and long numbers will automatically get modified by Excel. For example, if you type 012, it will be changed to 12.

If you format the cells as **Text**, then any number that you type in the cell will stay as is, and will not be modified by Excel.

However, if you paste a number from another source into a cell that is formatted as **Text**, and in the source there is any sort of formatting, the formatting of the cell will change from **Text** to **General**, and the number manipulation will come back.

The solution that I found was to do a paste special, and paste the number as **Text**. Then the cell remains with its **Text** formatting, and the number is not modified at all.