# Why does my exported CSV data get converted to weird formats?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I am using Microsoft Office 2007. I have an Excel file and need to convert it into a CSV File. When I save the file as CSV then some values are converted into another format

Before converting the 4<sup>th</sup> column shows the value `6000000116`:

[image: before: GROUP_HOF_ID = 6000000116]

After converting to CSV it shows `6E+09`:

[image: after: GROUP_HOF_ID = 6E+09]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: [might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22647042/1699210)

Answer (score 0):

It's simply because the width of the column is not enough for the precise value, therefore Excel displays it in [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation). It's the [same reason you see **######...**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-correct-a-error-bf801d0a-2a6e-44bd-a70e-0f780ae8f11e) in Excel files with a too narrow cell width

To show the exact value, resize the column to make it bigger. However you'll get the same "issue" the next time you open the file, because there's no column width information in CSV file like in xls/xlsx files

If you want to fix it *permanently* then you must format the cell/column as text (by prepending it with `'` or various other ways) before exporting, or set the column as text while importing the file using the wizard

- [How to import long number from csv to excel without converting to scientific notation in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13732077/995714)
- [How to save excel columns with long numbers into csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22647042/995714)

See also

- [Numbers in scientific notation imported to Excel 2016 as text](https://superuser.com/q/1277475/241386)
- [Editing CSV file in Excel always converts number column to scientific notation](https://superuser.com/q/1083454/241386)
- [How do I stop Excel from converting value 0503E000 to 5.03E+02 automatically?](https://superuser.com/q/861964/241386)
- [How can you make Excel 2007 stop formatting large numbers as scientific notation?](https://superuser.com/q/37975/241386)
- [How can I stop Excel from eating my delicious CSV files and excreting useless data?](https://superuser.com/q/234997/241386)
- [Re-opened .csv file changes the value of 0.000E+00 number format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46170588/995714)
- [Importing from a CSV modifies the number format into scientific notation (1,23E+18)](https://superuser.com/q/427420/241386)
- [Preventing numbers from appearing in exponential format in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12635604/995714)